# how to count two different values from same column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table `connection_master` in that table column name `status_conn` have 1 value for ON conn. and 2 for OFF conn. now I want to get only counts of ON and OFF connections in one query

I want output like this

```
on_counts   off_counts
110         55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status_conn = 1 THEN 1 END) AS on_counts,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status_conn = 2 THEN 1 END) AS off_counts
FROM connection_master;
```

Comment: yes, it's working. but now I want to add this query in Stored Procedure as a subquery after adding error comes up: - too many values

Comment: If you have a stored proc question, you may want to ask a new question.

Comment: its 90minutes buffer for new question

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(status_conn) AS CONN_ON,COUNT(status_conn) AS CONN_OFF
FROM connection_master where substr(status_conn,1,1) IN (1,2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   connection_master
PIVOT  (COUNT(*) FOR status_conn IN (1 AS on_count, 2 AS off_count));
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE connection_master (status_conn) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 110 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 55;
```

Outputs:

| ON_COUNT | OFF_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 110 | 55 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R7ynPVVq)